# jquery .mouseover() mouseout() item appears

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mouseout

I'm trying to get the item to hide itself on mouse over unfortunately it keeps showing up if mouse would stay frozen on the item for a while.

Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

I need this to stay hidden when mouse is kept over the item and appear only when mouse is out.

```js
$('#test').mouseover(function() {
  $('#test').hide();
});

$('#test').mouseout(function() {
  $('#test').fadeIn(500);
});
```

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test"></div>
```

<kbd>[**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/04wL1rb9/3/)</kbd>

Comment: It is great that you added a minimal test case using jsfiddle. But you should always include the relevant code with the question itself too. The questions   and answers here should not depend on external source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that hiding the element fire its mouse leave function because it's leaving the element itself while disappearing.

You can add a wrapping element like,

```
<div id="demo">
    <div id="test"></div>
</div>
```

and attach the event handlers on it.

Code:

```
$('#demo').mouseover(function () {
    $('#test').hide();
});
$('#demo').mouseout(function () {
    $('#test').fadeIn(500);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/04wL1rb9/15/

Answer (score 1):

It is intriguing what's happening with your code, it should work as far as I know. Have you tried just using CSS?

```
    #test {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    /* HOVER OFF */
    -webkit-transition: background-color 2s;
}
#test:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    /* HOVER ON */
    -webkit-transition: background-color 2s;
}
```

You can change the timing of the transitions. And don't forget to disable the jQuery code you included in your question. The same way I did it with the background, you can use "display". I hope this helps.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emfuentes27/26qnpa7d/)

Answer (score 1):

Use a container div to solve this. Reason: When the div disappears mouseout event is triggered.

```js
$('#container').mouseenter( function(){
  
       $('#test').fadeOut();
    console.log("enter");
 });
$('#container').mouseleave( function (){
        $('#test').fadeIn();
    console.log("leave");
});
```

```css
#test {
     width:100px;
     height:100px;
     background: blue;
     
 }

#container{
       width:100px;
     height:100px;
    position: absolute;
     top: 10px;
     left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<div id="test"></div>
</div>
```